# How can I check a valid user's phone number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am creating an input form on a web page. That's on field in phone number get in user.now How can I check now if the user's phone number is a wallet? my user lives in bangladesh.

Comment: What is the expected form?

Comment: this is not a code writing service, you're expected to try to solve your own problem first, not just ask for free coding from over-generous people

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to check mobile phone:

```
 ^\+?(88)?0?1[3456789][0-9]{8}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement real world project phone validation then there are two ways I know that can be used :-

After basic regex check on the phone number, you can.....

(i) setup an OTP based system so that user has to fill OTP on your page that was sent to his phone number to validate the number.

(ii) use a phone number validator api if you just want to check if the number is correct or not and belongs to a particular country. There are many free web api's present that you can use in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for that:

```
function validatePhone(phone){
    let p = ^\+?(88)?0?1[3456789][0-9]{8}\b;
    return p.test(phone);
}
```

Comment: @sumon Does it help somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate only the format of the number using javascript , but to know if it really exists you need to verify it. E.g is you assume your friend is there behind the wall but you can only be sure if he replies to you , same way you can only be sure if phone number exists if you send an OTP to it and verify that, Microsoft recently using watsapp OTP i noticed , likewise this service https://dbuddyz.com can provide free watsapp OTP delivery and there are others too but this one seems to be free. So which ever service you used , you can call an ajax function sending the OTP , storing the same on your side in a variable to avoid user knowing the values , may be encrypt it using md5 for example and when user enters the otp verify the md5 values stored and entered.